# Passing function pointers between functions

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am writing the program for Generic Stack.SO I pass the function pointer to the function `StackNew()` API. When I see the address of the `StringFree` API, it is `0x012b2770` ,

[image: Memory Window for StackNew]

but when I see the address of  (*free) API it is `0x012B13ED`

[image: Memory window for free]

I had thought that the pointer's copy will be passed . As you can see that's not happening but the program is working as it should .

I thought  that the starting address of the StringFree API is passed ,like suppose the starting address of StringFree is 0x10 then , 0x10 is passed to free API so that the free also points to starting address of StringFree so that the value of the free also will be 0x10 ,but that is not happening .Can you explain me what is going on here? Thanks.

My program :

```
#include<cstdio>  
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    void *elems;
    int loglen;
    int alloclen;
    int elemSize;
    void (*freefn) (void*);
}Stack;

void StringFree(void* target)
{
    char** s = (char**)target;
    free(*s);
    if (s != NULL) {
        std::cout << "Not null" << std::endl;
    }
    s = NULL;

}

void StackNew(Stack *s, int elemSize,void (*free) (void*))
{
    s->elemSize = elemSize;
    s->loglen = 0;
    s->alloclen = 4;
    s->elems = malloc(4 * elemSize);
    s->freefn = free;
    //assert(s->elems != 0 );

}

void StackDispose(Stack *s)
{
    if (s->freefn != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
        {
            void* source = (char*)s->elems + i*s->elemSize;
            s->freefn(source);
        }
    }

}

void StackPush(Stack *s, void* elemAddr)
{
    if (s->alloclen == s->loglen)
    {
        s->alloclen *= 2;
        s->elems = realloc(s->elems, s->alloclen * s->elemSize);

    }
    void* target = (char*)s->elems + s->loglen*s->elemSize;
    memcpy(target, elemAddr, s->elemSize);
    s->loglen++;

}

void* StackPop(Stack *s, void* elemAddr)
{
    s->loglen--;
    void* source = (char*)s->elems + s->loglen * s->elemSize;
    memcpy(elemAddr, source, s->elemSize);
    return elemAddr;
}


int main()
{

    Stack s;
    std::cout << sizeof(s.freefn) << std::endl;
    const char* friends[] = { "AlexJonesisabitchofjoerogan" , "Bob" , "Carl"};
    StackNew(&s, sizeof(char*),StringFree);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //int* cc = (int *)_strdup(friends[i]);
        char* copy = _strdup(friends[i]);
        std::cout << copy << std:: endl;
        StackPush(&s, &copy);
    }

    char* name;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        StackPop(&s, &name);
        printf("%s\n", name);
        // free()
    }

    StackDispose(&s);
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `As you can see that's not happening` I don't see that at all. Why do you think the pointer is not copied? What do you mean by `address of the StringFree API` and `address of (*free) API`?

Comment: I thought  that the starting address of the StringFree API is passed ,like suppose the starting address of StringFree is 0x10 then , 0x10 is passed to free API so that the free also points to starting address of StringFree so that the value of the free also will be 0x10 ,but that is not happening , This is what I mean.

Comment: What do you mean by API?

Comment: synonymous for function

Comment: What do you mean by  `address of (*free)` specifically? You mean the value of `free` pointer, right? How did you find out it's 0x012B13ED? How did you find out that `StringFree` starts at 0x012b2770?

Comment: By debugging .Yes I mean the value of free pointer.My question is if I am passing the function pointer both the passed value and the receiving value should have the same value

Comment: When I view the addresses in gdb, they match up.  What debugger are you  using, and how **exactly** are you printing these pointer values?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't printing the address the pointer is stored at rather than what it's referencing?

Comment: Yes I am sure . I was debugging it in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are still passed by value, so when you pass a pointer, it copies the value of the pointer as it would for an integer.

Comment: I know about this .But that s not my question